# Ember trying to update element gives this.get(...).save is not a function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to learn Ember, and i have gotten to read and write new elements to my backend server. I am somehow stuck when trying to update.

this is my controller

```
App.TeamController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
editMode : false,
actions : {
    enterEdit : function() {
        this.set('editMode', true);
    },
    saveEdit : function() {
        this.set('editMode', false);
        this.get('model').save();
    }
}});
```

And this is my handlebar code:

```
    {{# each team in model itemController="team"}}
    {{# if team.editMode}}
    {{input type="text" id="newName" value=team.name class="form-control"}}
    {{input type="text" id="newLevel" value=team.level class="form-control"}}
    <button {{action "saveEdit"}}>Save</button>
    {{else}}
     <p>{{team.name}} : {{team.level}} <button {{action 'enterEdit'}}>edit</button></p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

this gives me the following error message in the console:

TypeError: this.get(...).save is not a function.

I can not figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

My model:

```
App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
level: DS.attr('string')
```

});

my route

```
App.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function() {
    var team = $.get('/teams/');
    team.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    return team;
}});
```

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint on `this.get('model').save();` and run `this.get('model')`? Is a model returned?

Comment: Like Oren is suggesting mostlikely you don't have a model, what does your route look like?

Comment: If I set the breakpoint I do get an object, it has all the values as the model, it is: Object { id: 2, name: Getter, level: Getter, 2 more… }, but it still gives me .save() is not a function.

Comment: My route looks like: App.TeamsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model : function() {
  var team = $.get('/teams/');
  team.then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
  return team;
 }
 
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which I've found a very "hacky" solution for.

Instead of:

```
model.save()
```

try this:

```
model.get('content').save()
```

This worked for me, although as a solution I'm not keen. Does anyone have cleaner work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but the issue is actually being caused by this.get('model') returning a promise rather than the ember data model ( hence why get('content') works ). The easiest solution to clean this up would be to modify your code to be the following

```
App.TeamController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
editMode : false,
actions : {
    enterEdit : function() {
        this.set('editMode', true);
    },
    saveEdit : function() {
        this.set('editMode', false);
        //this properly handles the promise that is returned 
        this.get('model').then(m => m.save());
    }
}});
```

Comment: I would not know if it works, The code is long gone, and I moved on to react instead :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't figure you would. I just left this here for whoever else stumbles across it.

Answer (score 2):

Your model seems to be an array of instances, since you're looping over it. You can't save an array of models. Instead, pass the current model to the action and save that specific one:

```
<button {{action "saveEdit" team}}>  {{! pass team to action }}
    Save
</button>
```

Then save that specific model:

```
saveEdit : function(model) {         // <== add parameter
    this.set('editMode', false);
    model.save();                    // <== save the specific model
}
```

Comment: This gives me the exact same object as described above, it has Id, name and level, but save is not a function of the object.

Comment: Is model an array or not, and if it is, an array of what, created how?

Comment: what I am trying to do is recreate something like the example here: 
[link](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/) 
First there is an array of models and then passing one and one to a controller that handles an object.